# Failed to pull image with policy : image pull failed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I am getting below error while pulling image from Artifactory repository. I am using Gitlab Runner to set the configuration

```
Waiting for pod sai/runner-dan3u2t-project-9879-concurrent-0zdmgf to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper svc-0]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper svc-0]"

WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech"
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech"
```

Below is the value file I used to create gitlab runner

```
gitlabUrl: 'https://gitlab.bayer.com/'
runnerRegistrationToken: **********
rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountName: ************
serviceAccount.name: *************


resources:
  limits:
    memory: 16000Mi
    cpu: 2000m
  requests:
    memory: 16000Mi
    cpu: 2000m

runners:
  privileged: true
```

Should i make change to values file or gitlab files to get this corrected.Any idea ?

Comment: What is the URL of your Artifactory repo? Docker image tags that do not start with a server hostname will be downloaded from the public Docker hub so you cannot simply use `aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech` to refer to your private Artifactory.

Comment: https://artifactory.***.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python/3.6-strech/      this is the repo. Should I use it raw as it is ?

Comment: yes, for docker images in repos other than docker hub, you need to include full URL

Comment: Iused the full url but still getting below error : ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: image pull failed: Failed to apply default image tag "https://artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python/3.6-strech": couldn't parse image reference "https://artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python/3.6-strech": invalid reference format.

Comment: You need to check in your Artifactory what is the actual URL to use. Don't try and error.

Comment: Issue is persistence and open here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27664